# What canon lenses should I buy?

Tags: lens

I am looking to buy 3 canon lenes for my EOS 7D. What are the three best lenses that will help give me different ranges. I want to get a fast general purpose zoom lens, a macro lens and a telephoto zoom.

Comment: There is no possible way that we could answer what the best lenses are for three different lenses without knowing a million more questions.  I'm voting to close this. Two options as far as I'm concerned, with the second being highly favored.  1.  Ask about each lens individually, and tell us what you want to use it for and your budget.  2.  Ask a question about each about *HOW* to pick those lenses - what factors to consider, what the options are, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Since you didn't give any specifics about what you photograph or a price range, I'll just recommend three great lenses in those ranges.

- [Canon EF-S 17-55mm f/2.8](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/425812-USA/Canon_1242B002AA_EF_S_17_55mm_f_2_8_IS.html)
- [Canon EF 100mm f/2.8L Macro](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/647011-USA/Canon_3554B002_EF_100mm_f_2_8L_Macro.html)
- [Canon EF 70-200mm f/2.8L IS II](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/680103-USA/Canon_2751B002_EF_70_200mm_f_2_8L_IS.html)

If you have a budget in mind, or any other details about your intended use for the lenses, please update your question.  As it's currently worded, it's kind of broad.

Comment: I'll add the Canon EF-S 10-22mm f/3.5-4.5 to that list.  You could also grab some primes, 30mm, 50mm,85mm, etc.

Answer (score 2):

My 3 recommendation would all all be 'L' glass:
 - Canon EF 16-35mm f/2.8L II USM Autofocus Lens
 - Canon EF 24-70mm f/2.8L USM Zoom Wide Angle-Telephoto Lens
 - Canon EF 70-200mm f/2.8L IS II USM Telephoto Zoom Lens

With these lenses you know you are getting the best. The Kenko extension tubes for Macro.

Comment: On APS-C, I would argue that the 17-55mm f/2.8 IS is better then the "L" designation.

Comment: @dpolitt, As someone who recently owned a 17-55 and replaced it with a 16-35 it is my opinion that the 17-55 just doesn't come close to the 16-35 for my needs. I know I am in the minority of people who are posting about these two lenses, but I was really unhappy with the 17-55.